# Selecting customers who have spent more than a certain amount in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sales table which has one row for each sales tranaction.  This table has date of sale and customer id as well.

I am looking for a way to select all those customers who have total spending in the specified range with in a specified date range.  For example, get all customers who spent `between 100 and 1000`, `between 2016-07-01 and 2016-08-15`.  This then has to become part of a larger query.

This query

```
select 
   customer_id, 
   sum(sale_amount) 
from 
   sales_receipt 
where 
   DATE(sales_receipt.sale_date) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-29' 
group by
   customer_id;
```

gives me all customers and their total spending in the specified date range but I need only those customers for whom `sum(sale_amount)` is `between 100 and 1000`.

Can any one help.

Comment: Then do so? `AND sum(sale_amount) BETWEEN 100 AND 1000` You already said the answer yourself, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: it's obvious, group by customer_id Having sum(sale_amount) between(100,1000)

Comment: Incidentally, appropriately indexed, `WHERE sales_receipt.sale_date BETWEEN '2016-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-29 23:59:59'` will perform faster. This can have a significant impact on larger data sets.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  It did speed the query up significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
        select customer_id, sum(sale_amount) from sales_receipt where
DATE(sales_receipt.sale_date) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-29' 
            group by customer_id having sum(sale_amount)>=100 and sum(sale_amount)<=100
```

Comment: This worked.  What I was missing was the having clause.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the `HAVING` clause here because you want to [filter on the aggregated result](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  SUM(sale_amount) AS total_amount
FROM sales_receipt
WHERE DATE(sales_receipt.sale_date) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-29'
HAVING total_amount BETWEEN 100 AND 1000
GROUP BY customer_id;
```